# Multidimension Array In Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Basically, user have to specify how the many row and column they want [n*n] and after that user will input value and it will store in multidimension array.I run the code but getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at Total.main(Total.java:30)

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Total
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int n,value;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter integer for row and column:");
n = input.nextInt();

int arrX[][] = new int [n][n];

for(int i=0; i < n; i++ )
{
    for(int j=0; j < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter integer [%d],[%d]:",i,j);
        value = input.nextInt();
        arrX[i][j] = value;
    }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: In such exceptions you can check console output and figure out what can be wrong. Then, it's easy to find bug, because j is never larger than 0 :)

Answer (score 5):

In the line:

```
for(int j=0; j < n; i++)
```

you increase `i` where it should be `j` like this:

```
for(int j=0; j < n; j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
for(int j=0; j < n; **j**++)
```

it's a typo perhaps

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `i` in both loops.

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Total
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int n,value;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter integer for row and column:");
    n = input.nextInt();

    int arrX[][] = new int [n][n];

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter integer [%d],[%d]:",i,j);
            value = input.nextInt();
            arrX[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop you do `i++` instead of `j++`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you increment the wrong variable in the second for:

```
for(int j=0; j < n; i++)
```

Instead of i you must type j

Works fine if you change this.

Cheers